# Difference between serializeData and onRender in Marionette.CompositeView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am using [`Marionette.CompositeView`](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md) and I would like to understand the difference between serializeData and onRender
based on these two exemple (1) and (2).

According the documentation serializeData is called in render before applying the template, and onRender is called in render after applying the template.

My questions are:
1) why the example (1) works and the (2) does not?
2) If I reset the collection, will the `Marionette.CompositeView` be re-rendered?

Please see the comments in the code for more details.

---

(1)

```
return Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this.collection = new MyCollection();
            this.collection.fetch();
        },

        onRender: function () {
            this.collection.length > 0 ? this.$el.show() : this.$el.hide();
           // it returns this.collection.length > 0 
           // differently from serializeData.
        }
});
```

---

(2)

```
return Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this.collection = new MyCollection();
            this.collection.fetch();
        },

        serializeData: function () {
            this.collection.length > 0 ? this.$el.show() : this.$el.hide(); 
           // it returns this.collection.length = 0 
           // even if this.collection.length > 0. Why?
        }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

1) As you said, `onRender` is just a callback function which is called after rendering the view.

`serializeData` must return a valid JSON object as it's said in the [Backbone Marionette documentation](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md) :

> If you need custom serialization for your data, you can provide a
>   serializeData method on your view. It must return a valid JSON object,
>   as if you had called .toJSON on a model or collection.

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  serializeData: function(){
    return {
      "some attribute": "some value"
    }
  }

});
```

2) IMO, the answer is yes. In the [Backbone Marionette documentation](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md), it's said :

> CollectionView: Automatic Rendering
>
> The collection view binds to the "add", "remove" and "reset" events of
>   the collection that is specified.
>
> When the collection for the view is "reset", the view will call render
>   on itself and re-render the entire collection.
>
> When a model is added to the collection, the collection view will
>   render that one model in to the collection of item views.
>
> When a model is removed from a collection (or destroyed / deleted),
>   the collection view will close and remove that model's item view.

Comment: +1 thanks for your response. Anyway, about the (1), I cannot understand from your reply why  `this.collection.length = 0` in serializeData while in `onRender` is `this.collection.length > 0`.

Comment: I suppose that it's because the serializeData method must be only used to prepare data to be displayed. That's why there is another callback method which is "beforeRender".

Comment: the only thing I would add to this is that the two methods serve completely different functions and are called at very different times. don't use one for the job of the other. look at the method names to give you an idea of what they do. `serializeData` serializes the data that is used to render your template. `onRender` gets called immediately after the view has been rendered.

Comment: if that doesn't clear it up, add some `debugger;` calls to the `serializeData` and `onRender` of one of your views and run it with your dev tools turns on in your browser. you'll very quickly see when each is called. also look at the source code. it's well documented and well formatted. you'll learn a lot by reading the code yourself.